# Cannot read property 'length' of undefined at type in javascript

Tags: javascript, undefined

I have 2 errors:
Cannot read property 'length' of undefined at type and typing.
What is wrong?

```
setTimeout(function typing() {

var fields = document.querySelectorAll('input');
var text = ["text", "text", "text", "text"];

function print (input, num, timeout) {
    setTimeout(function(){
        var i = 0;
        function type(){
            if (i <= text[num].length) {
        input.value = text[num].substr(0, i);
        setTimeout(type, 100);
            }
            console.log(text[num].length);
            i++;
        }
        type();
        console.log(type());
        if (num == 3) {
        setTimeout(
            function() {
            document.getElementById('postlogo_animation').className +=" postlogo-img"
            },text[num].length * 120);
        }
    }, timeout);
}

for (var b = 0; b < fields.length; b++) {
    var timeout = 0;
    var input = fields[b];
    if (b > 0) {
        for (var c = 0; c < b; c++) {
            timeout += text[c].length * 140
        }
    }
    print(input, b, timeout)
}}, 1000);
```

Cannot read property 'length' of undefined at type and typing.
What is wrong?
[here is console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5aiFH.png)

Comment: What is the maximum value of `num`? If `num` gets greater than 3, `text[num]` gets undefined.